# Multiples images in Header adapting to screen resolution CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to setup a frame for my new website but I have a problem on some screen resolutions. It seems like my image `banner-logo.png` is too big at some times (regarding the users screen resolution).

I am trying to figure out a way that my whole top banner would **resize so it would fit based on the user's screen resolution**.

I would also like to center align my menu to the center of the div (which is 100% width).

Here is what I have to so far:

```css
    body {
        background-color: #000000;
        color: white;
    }
    img, object, embed, canvas, video, audio, picture {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    ul {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        list-style-type:none;
    }
    li {
        margin-left:0px;
        float:left;
        /*pour IE*/
    }
    ul li a {
        display: inline;
        color:white;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-align:center;
        padding:15px;
    }
    ul li a:hover {
        color: yellow;
    }
    div#header {
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url("../images/banner-bg.jpg");
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    div#top-banner {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0px;
        border: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        height: 453px;
    }
    div#gars-gauche {
        float: left;
        width: 333px;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url("../images/gars-gauche.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: inline;
    }
    div#banner-centre {
        height: 453px;
        max-width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align:middle;
        display: inline;
    }
    div#gars-droite {
        float: right;
        width: 333px;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url("../images/gars-droite.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: inline;
    }
    div#top-menu {
        position:relative;
        top: 20px;
        left: 80px;
    }
    div#content {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        padding-top: 35px;
    }
    h1 {
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
    <html>      
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        </head>
        
        <body>
            <div id="header">
                <div id="top-banner">
                    <div id="gars-gauche"></div>
                    <div id="banner-centre">
                        <img src="images/banner-logo.png" alt="banner" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="gars-droite"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="top-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">ACCUEIL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">MODÈLES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">TARIFS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">POLITIQUE</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">PARTENAIRES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">RECRUTEMENT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">WEBCAM</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="content">
                    <h1>BIENVENUE CHEZ LES GENTLEMEN'S</h1>
    
                    <hr />
                    <h3>SERVICE D'ACCOMPAGNEMENT POUR HOMMES ET FEMMES DE TOUS ÂGES</h3>
    
                    <p>Les Gentlemen's sont fiers d'offrir aux hommes et femmes un service d'accompagnement de qualité supérieur dans le secteur de Montréal et ses environs.</p>
                    <p>Vous avez envie d'un souper romantique, d'une sortie au cinéma ou d'un moment de tendresse?</p>
                    <p>Nos Gentlemen's s'engagent à vous offrir un moment inoubliable!</p>
                    <a href="http://zonevideo.telequebec.tv/media/18521/emission-428/les-francs-tireurs" target="_new"><img src="images/Banner-les-francs-tireur.jpg" alt="Les Francs Tireurs"/></a>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <a href="https://soundcloud.com/les-gentlemens/entrevue-boom-1041fm" target="_new"><img src="images/Banner-Osez-les-gentlemens.jpg" /></a>
    
                </div>
                <div id="footer"></div>
            </div>
        </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: use style tags for applying css, Can you see the code now, and is images are loading while loading in your webpage?

Comment: Have you tried `background-size:cover;` in your css for the banner?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a fully variable height on your banner, I suggest you use the viewport width unit assigned to your font size, and then scale everything else using EM. As to your question about centering, you can center `inline` items with `text-align: center;`

The `em` unit is the same as your font size, so you can also size any images you would like to use with `em` and they will scale with the `font-size: 1.3vw;`.

```css
#top-menu {
    font-size: 1.3vw;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 1em;
}

#dog {
    width: 12em;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-menu">
<img id="dog" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/dog-clipart-pT5qj6ETB.png">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ACCUEIL</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">MODÈLES</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">TARIFS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">POLITIQUE</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">PARTENAIRES</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">RECRUTEMENT</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">WEBCAM</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">FACEBOOK</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you would only like to resize images and not text, you can just set their width as a percentage of the screen width using `width: 10vw;` for 10% of the viewport width.

Comment: I did changed it on my site but the problem remains the same. As soon as the screen width is smaller, the top banner changes line for each item (image on left, logo and image on right)...

Comment: Is your padding variable or static on your menu items? The padding needs to be variable. Can you update your question with a screenshot of the problem because it is hard to decipher what you are looking for from what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

For centering the menu try this:

CSS:

```
ul {
padding:0;
list-style-type:none;
}
li {
margin-left:0px;
display:inline-block;
}
div#top-menu {
position:relative;
top: 20px;
text-align:center;
}
```

For making the banner full size it is hard to say without seeing it in action. I would recommend starting with using `background-size:cover;`

```css
body {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
}
img, object, embed, canvas, video, audio, picture {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
ul {
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
li {
    margin-left:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    /*pour IE*/
}
ul li a {
    display: inline;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    padding:15px;
}
ul li a:hover {
    color: yellow;
}
div#header {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("../images/banner-bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    width: 100%;
}
div#top-banner {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 453px;
}
div#gars-gauche {
    float: left;
    width: 333px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("../images/gars-gauche.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline;
}
div#banner-centre {
    height: 453px;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display: inline;
}
div#gars-droite {
    float: right;
    width: 333px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("../images/gars-droite.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline;
}
div#top-menu {
    position:relative;
    top: 20px;
    text-align:center;

}
div#content {
      text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 35px;
}
h1 {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
       <div id="header">
            <div id="top-banner">
                <div id="gars-gauche"></div>
                <div id="banner-centre">
                    <img src="images/banner-logo.png" alt="banner" />
                </div>
                <div id="gars-droite"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="top-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">ACCUEIL</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MODÈLES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TARIFS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">POLITIQUE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PARTENAIRES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">RECRUTEMENT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">WEBCAM</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <h1>BIENVENUE CHEZ LES GENTLEMEN'S</h1>

                <hr />
                <h3>SERVICE D'ACCOMPAGNEMENT POUR HOMMES ET FEMMES DE TOUS ÂGES</h3>

                <p>Les Gentlemen's sont fiers d'offrir aux hommes et femmes un service d'accompagnement de qualité supérieur dans le secteur de Montréal et ses environs.</p>
                <p>Vous avez envie d'un souper romantique, d'une sortie au cinéma ou d'un moment de tendresse?</p>
                <p>Nos Gentlemen's s'engagent à vous offrir un moment inoubliable!</p>
                <a href="http://zonevideo.telequebec.tv/media/18521/emission-428/les-francs-tireurs" target="_new"><img src="images/Banner-les-francs-tireur.jpg" alt="Les Francs Tireurs"/></a>
                <br />
                <br />
                <a href="https://soundcloud.com/les-gentlemens/entrevue-boom-1041fm" target="_new"><img src="images/Banner-Osez-les-gentlemens.jpg" /></a>

            </div>
            <div id="footer"></div>
        </div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/518m8few/)